# Hidding an element when on mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am developing a website and I need few div tags to hide when I'm on the mobile version and certain conditions are met.

I usually hide div tags with jQuery or CSS but I can't do this here. The div tags are created with a PHP foreach printing a query. And some of the results must not show on the mobile version of the website. But I still need those results to show on the desktop version.

```
if ($article->reference > 0) {
    if ($article->apothema > 1) {
        if ($catalogue->id == 2) {
            $qty = "<img title='Διαθέσιμο' alt='Διαθέσιμο' src='" . Mage::getBaseUrl('skin') . "frontend/default/b2b/images/diathesimo.png'><span style='padding-left: 10px;font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;color: #58595B;'>" . $this->__('Άμεσα Διαθέσιμο') . "</span>";
        } else {
            $qty = "<img title='Διαθέσιμο' alt='Διαθέσιμο' src='" . Mage::getBaseUrl('skin') . "frontend/default/b2b/images/diathesimo.png'><span style='padding-left: 10px;font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;color: #58595B;'>" . $this->__('Available') . "</span>";
        }
        echo "<span style='display:none;'></span>" . $qty . "<span style='font-size:14px;color:#58595B;font-weight:bold;padding-left: 50px;'></span>";
    } elseif ($article->getApothema() == 1) {
        $qty = "<img title='Διαθέσιμο' alt='Διαθέσιμο' src='" . Mage::getBaseUrl('skin') . "frontend/default/b2b/images/diathesimo.png'><span style='padding-left: 10px;font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;color: #58595B;'>" . $this->__('Αμεσα Διαθέσιμο') . "</span>";
        echo "<span style='display:none;'></span>" . $qty . "<span style='font-size:14px;color:#58595B;font-weight:bold;padding-left: 50px;'></span>";
    } elseif ($article->getApothema() < 1) {
        $qty = "<img title='Μη Διαθέσιμο' alt='Διαθέσιμο' src='" . Mage::getBaseUrl('skin') . "frontend/default/b2b/images/midiathesimo.png'><span style='padding-left: 10px;font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;color: #58595B;'>" . $this->__('Not Available') . "</span>";
        echo "<span style='display:none;'></span>" . $qty . "<span style='font-size:14px;color:#58595B;font-weight:bold;padding-left: 50px;'></span>";
    }
}
```

This is the condition based upon the div tags are to hide or show on mobile. 
If the condition `($article->getApothema() < 1)` is truthy, the tags must be hidden, otherwise they should be shown. On desktop it should always show.

What this part of the code actually do is checking the availability of some items in a warehouse and displays accordingly green for plenty, orange for few and red when none is available. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use media queries, a lot easier.

Comment: how do you establish, in PHP, whether or not is mobile? Are you using mobiledetect?

Comment: What is different about the three (or four) conditions? Is it just a different image at different screen sizes?

Comment: Why can't you use css? if you don't use css, how do you want to hide it, in the php code?

Comment: @asobak media queries can't check if conditions as far as I know, just the screen resolution.

Comment: @GrafiCode nope, just a responsive website.

Comment: @showdev different colour image and a different span description.

Comment: @litzel Yeah, but you can combine both.

Comment: @litzel if you want to handle it in PHP you need a server-side component which tells you what device client is on. Otherwise, as many suggested, you can handle it in CSS

Comment: @winner_joiner the problem with CSS is that you can't use if conditions in CSS.

Comment: I would write out different classes based on the different conditions in PHP, and then show or hide things based on those classes and/or the screen size via media queries.

Comment: @litzel you can print classes in your html code using PHP, and then code your CSS accordingly

Comment: @GrafiCode could you use an example with conditions in CSS please?

Comment: @showdev that should be the accepted solution to this problem

Comment: in PHP `class="<?php if ($article->getApothema() < 1) print('mobInvisible'); ?>"` and then you style it in CSS `.mobInvisible { display: none; }`

Comment: And thats literally what I've meant with using media queries and combining them.

Comment: @showdev no unfortunately this can't be done. As I said the tags are made through a foreach and the availability check is done afterwards. If you place a class, all the elements in the produced list will have, won't separate the available ones from the not available ones. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @GrafiCode I'll try this, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "the availability check is done afterwards"?

Comment: @GrafiCode it seems to have worked, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries. Adn class thatis hidden when screen has mobile width and then in php echo that class into elements you want hide.

````
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .mobile{
        display:none;        #2 options how to hide elemet
        visibility:hidden;   
    }

PHP
echo 
    foreach
            <div class="mobile"></div>
```
````

Comment: You either put display: none; or visibility: hidden;, not both. Note that while using visibility: hidden; it still takes blank space on page.

Comment: I know thats why i add that comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [library](http://mobiledetect.net/) to detect if a user uses a mobile. To use it, you can do it this way.

```
// Include and instantiate the class.
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

// Any mobile device (phones or tablets).
if ( ($detect->isMobile()) && ($article->getApothema() < 1) ) {
    //data show specifically for mobile 
}else{
    //show data for Desktop
}
```